# Character table of a cyclic group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I am trying to verify the orthogonality relations for characters of a cyclic group $C_3$. First I am trying to prove that all the rows are orthogonal. However if one refers to the character table http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_table. I am stuck at $X_1$ and $X_2$ which is yielding non orthogonal relations.

My work:

$<X_1, X_2> = 1(1)+\omega(\omega^{2})+\omega^{2}(\omega)=1(1)+\omega^{3}+\omega^{3}$. Since our $\omega=e^{2\pi(i)/3}$. This expression simplifies to $1+1+1=3$ and is clearly not orthogonal. Thus, am I missing something trivial here?

Comment: Yes- you did not apply complex conjugation to the second character. If you do that, you get $1+\omega\cdot\omega^{-2}+\omega^2\cdot\omega^{-1}=1+\omega^2+\omega=0$.

Comment: And don't forget to divide by the order of the group (3) to verify the irreducibility ($[\chi,\chi]=1$).

Comment: @NickyHekster: Thank you. I have been able to verify them all

Comment: @KReiser: Yes!!! I just overlooked that.. thanks